# Obiective-C, find global variable at Runtime?

Tags: objective-c

I am curious to know if there is any way to find a global variable at runtime, much like NSClassFromString. The variable, a BOOL, is defined in a static library and I found the name by using "nm" which gave this output: "0001924d b _gStartSessionCalled". When debugging in XCode I can add an expression "gStartSessionCalled" and see the value change as the app is running.

What I want to do is find the value of gStartSessionCalled and also change the value. I know it's kind of weird to do this but please disregard the reason why.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the debugger or in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lowercase letter "b" in the nm output

```
0001924d b _gStartSessionCalled
```

indicates that `gStartSessionCalled` is a local (non-external) symbol. It could for example be defined as

```
static BOOL gStartSessionCalled;
```

in your library. As far as I know, you cannot access local symbols from outside the object file in which it they are defined.

The debugger can use the symbol table to find the address and display the variable, but the linker refuses to link against a local symbol from a different object file.

Comment: Guess it's impossible then. Too bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A global variable is not an Objective-C specific construct. It is plain C and you can access every global variable when knowing its name by declaring it like

```
extern <type> <name>;
```

e.g. in your case

```
extern BOOL gStartSessionCalled;
…
gStartSessionCalled = YES;
```

**Update:**

If you do not know the name of the variable at compile time, you still may find the symbols address at runtime using something like `dlsym`. I don't know if it is the same on MacOS as on Linux, but there will be something similar.

Comment: Where do I need to put that though? I tried it already and I get a linker error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_gStartSessionCalled", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o

Comment: Which library does contain the symbol? You may link against this library or tell your compiler to ignore undefined symbols.

Comment: It's called libFlurryAnalytics.

Comment: Martin R had stated in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12689962/76663) that the symbol is local. Then you cannot access it by declaring it `extern` (as Martin also said). If you are interested in hacking you still may find it at runtime and using its address to modify it.